# Warnings in FileReference - can not find the cause

Tags: apache-flex, file-upload, flash-builder

I'm trying to make a loader of a few photos (use FileReference). I get the warnings, but I do not know the reason for their appearance.

warning: unable to bind to property 'fr' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
warning: unable to bind to property 'name' on class 'flash.net::FileReference'
warning: unable to bind to property 'data' on class 'flash.net::FileReference'
warning: unable to bind to property 'fr' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
warning: unable to bind to property 'name' on class 'flash.net::FileReference'
warning: unable to bind to property 'data' on class 'flash.net::FileReference'

```
import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
import flash.net.FileReferenceList;
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

[Bindable]
private var photos:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
private var frList:FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList;

private function init():void
{
photos.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE,function():void
{ 
startUploadButton.enabled = (photos.length>0);
clearPhotosButton.enabled = (photos.length>0);
});
frList.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,addPhotos);
}

private function selectPhotos():void
{
var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images jpeg","*.jpg;*.jpeg");
frList.browse([fileFilter]);
}

private function addPhotos(e:Event):void
{
for (var i:uint = 0; i < frList.fileList.length; i++)
{
var elem:Object = new Object;
elem.fr = FileReference(frList.fileList[i]);
elem.fr.load();
elem.fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,refreshThumb);
photos.addItem(elem);
}
}

private function refreshThumb(e:Event):void
{
photosList.invalidateList();
}

public function clearPhoto(data:Object):void
{
photos.removeItemAt(photos.getItemIndex(data));
photosList.invalidateList();
}

private function startUpload():void
{
photosProgressContainer.visible = true;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = "http://localhost/tempLoader-debug/upload.php";
var fr:FileReference = photos.getItemAt(0).fr;
fr.cancel();
fr.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,uploadProgress);
fr.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA,uploadComplete);
fr.upload(request);
}

private function uploadProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
photosProgress.setProgress(e.bytesLoaded,e.bytesTotal);
}

private function uploadComplete(e:DataEvent):void
{
photos.removeItemAt(0);
photosList.invalidateList();
if (photos.length > 0) 
startUpload();
else
photosProgressContainer.visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This warnings occur because you try to bind to properties `fr`, `FileReference.name` and `FileReference.data` in your item renderer or somewhere. It may not bother you (don't know all you code) but to avoid them do the following:

### Strong-typed data provider

Fill `photos` with objects of special class like:

```
public class Photo
{
    public function Photo(fileReference:FileReference)
    {
        this.fileReference = fileReference;
    }

    public var fileReference:FileReference;

    [Bindable("__NoChangeEvent__")] // __NoChangeEvent__ is a special name
    public function get name():String
    {
        return fileReference.name;
    }

    [Bindable("__NoChangeEvent__")]
    public function get data():*
    {
        return fileReference.data;
    }
}
```

Then replace the code:

```
var elem:Object = new Object;
elem.fr = FileReference(frList.fileList[i]);
elem.fr.load();
elem.fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,refreshThumb);
photos.addItem(elem);
```

With the following:

```
var elem:Photo = new Photo(frList.fileList[i]);
elem.fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,refreshThumb);
elem.fileReference.load();
photos.addItem(elem);
```

You should also change all the code that uses `photos` collection accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Maxim, but I do not really understand how to use this class (Photo) in my project. I create and add a new AS class and imported into the project (import Photo;) and warnings were.